# JsonConvertDeserializeObject not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I messed up somewhere and I am having some trouble with getting the JsonConvert to convert a response to my model. I am trying to call the twitch endpoint here: https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/CHANNEL/chatters and get the list of viewers.

Here is my code:

````
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var res = await client.GetAsync("https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/" + streamer + "/chatters").ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var str = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<response>(str);
                return response;
            }
            return null;
        }```


and finally here is my model:
````

```
public  class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("chatter_count")]
    public long ChatterCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("broadcaster")]
    public string[] Broadcaster { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vips")]
    public string[] Vips { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("moderators")]
    public string[] Moderators { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("staff")]
    public object[] Staff { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("admins")]
    public object[] Admins { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("global_mods")]
    public object[] GlobalMods { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("viewers")]
    public string[] Viewers { get; set; }
}
```

}```

Whenever I try to call my method to get the viewers I am getting App.Response with everything in the model being null even though whenever I use the same URL to in Postman or browser I get valid data back. and the

> var str = ""{\n  "_links": {},\n  "chatter_count": 2,\n
> "chatters": {\n    "broadcaster": [],\n    "vips": [],\n
> "moderators": [\n      "nightbot"\n    ],\n    "staff": [],\n
> "admins": [],\n    "global_mods": [],\n    "viewers": [\n
> "heirmanttinan"\n    ]\n  }\n}\n""

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=1qmkioWcQZOS0H6U7E8F (that website solves 95% of C# JSON questions).

Comment: thank you @mjwills I used that example and it is working now. I appreciate your time!